# - Security Notification -

Tags: webviewclient

- Security Notification - Your app is using an unsafe implementation of the WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError handler. Please visit the Google Customer Center Help for more details, such as the time of the vulnerability resolution. Vulnerable class: Org.mospi.moml.framework.pub.ui.MOMLWebViewClient Affects version 7 of the APK.

Comment: You will likely need to provide further details to allow others (with more knowledge than I of Google API's) to diagnose the issue. Such details might include code snippets around calls to WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError, as that is what seems to be causing the problem.

Comment: 응용 프로그램의 WebView SSL 오류 WebViewClient.onReceivedSslError 핸들에서 응용 프로그램 개발자를위한 정보가 필요합니다. 모든 SSL 인증서 확인 오류가 응용 프로그램에 저장되었습니다. WebView의 콘텐츠가 변경되고 전송 된 데이터 (예 : 로그인 사용자 인증 정보)가 콘텐츠 내부의 애플리케이션을 내부적으로 변경합니다. 2016 년 11 월 25 일 Google Play에서 새로운 앱 또는 업데이트 게시를 중단하십시오. 게시 된 APK 버전은 모든 앱 업데이트가 중단 된 것입니다. SSL 오류 처리기에 대한 자세한 정보는 Android 개발자 도구의 도움말을 참조하십시오. 기술 관련 질문 다른은 stackoverflow.com/questions에 '안드로이드 보안'및 'SslErrorHandler'태그를 추가하여 게시하세요. - @DW42